# Which all assertions can we use with fitnesse

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

For xml soap webservices testing which all assertions can we implement with fitnesse. For example Not soap fault, schema compliance, Soap response etc. I am using slim fixtures. 
Hope I can get some help as I am not able to find any user guide about this .
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slim is a test system, which fixtures do you (plan to) use? Slim itself knows nothing of web services or Xml. With [XmlHttpTest](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/wiki/2.-Slim-Fixtures#xmlhttptest) you would validate response content using xPath expressions on the response, this does not allow you to do schema validation.

When you use Slim I expect you will use script and scenario tables. The test system offers 'check', 'ensure', 'reject', 'check not' and 'ensure not'. What you can do with these depends on your fixtures.

See http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ScriptTable for more information on how to use a script.

Comment: Of course you CAN check schema compliance, but you would need to write your own fixture that knows where to get the schema and validates the response against that. Checking soap fault or normal responses is a matter of writing the xPath expressions to locate the element in the response you want to check, and providing the expected value.